# svn check out a sub-folder in repository

Tags: svn

I am having issues checking out a subfolder of a repository named 'pro'. I have subversion 1.7 installed and the repo is in /home/svn/pro

```
root@ubuntu: /home/svn/proroot@ubuntu:/home/svn/pro# dir
conf  db  format  hooks  locks    README.txt  src  typescript
root@ubuntu: /home/svn/proroot@ubuntu:/home/svn/pro# sudo svn co file://localhost  /home/svn    /pro/src /home/barry/testrepo
svn: E170000: URL 'file://localhost/home/svn/pro/src' doesn't exist
root@ubuntu: /home/svn/proroot@ubuntu:/home/svn/pro# exit
exit
```

any ideas why i cannot check out the subfolder pro/src? 
I can check out the /pro folder

Answer (score 1):

> why i cannot check out the subfolder pro/src?

Because this folder is **physical folder** and not part of repository.

Read at least SVN-Book as **a must ABC**, detect **real repository tree** using SVN-client and **correct** `file:///`-type URL of repository: for repository in `/home/svn/pro` it will be `svn ls [-R] file:///home/svn/pro`